# Raspberry pi 5 uart2 and uart4 problem

Tags: hardware, 23.10

I'm struggling to get uart2 and uart4 to work on the raspberry pi5 with Ubuntu 23.10 - kernel 6.5 kernel 6.5.0-1008-raspi.

I have loopback wired on GPIO4/5 - TXD2/RXD2, on GPIO12/13 - TXD4/RXD4, and on TXD0/RXD0:

4+5 (pins 7+29) and 12+13 (pins 32/33) are connected together.

I can boot the image on a Raspberry Pi4 and with the loopback in place.  I can use Minicom and see characters I type being echod back to me.

However, on the Raspberry Pi5, I'm unable to make this work.  I've tried everything I can think of and have trawled the forums and even asked the AI (who told me there was only one uart on the Raspberry pi5, which I don't think is right, but maybe it is?).

Loopback on UART0 works fine on the pi4 and pi5.

I have the following in config.txt

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=uart0-pi5
dtoverlay=uart2-pi5
dtoverlay=uart4-pi5
```

Interestingly when I boot with that I don't see any additional /dev/AMA* devices present.  I need to do:

```
sudo dtoverlay uart0-pi5
sudo dtoverlay uart2-pi5
sudo dtoverlay uart4-pi5
```

To see /dev/ttyAMA0, /dev/ttyAMA2 and /dev/ttyAMA4

This throws a warning "DTOVERLAY[warn]: no matching platform found", but from what I've read this can be ignored.  I've also checked `dmesg | grep uart`, this doesn't show any errors.

`sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0`

Works.  However:

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA2
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA4
```

does not.  Even though doing the same thing with the same loopback connector on a Pi4 does.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record, this is a bootloader issue (regression): https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/issues/514

Answer (score 0):

Jmonnz, there is [a thread on the Raspberry official forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=361397#p2171244) about this issue.

> When the `/boot/firmware/network-config` file is present, the overlays are not loaded. If that file is removed, the overlays load without issue.

Comment: Hi, ReDaLeRt, thanks for the info, its much appreciated.  I think the comment on the thread you quoted:

"However, the pinmuxing isn't working as it should, so although the /dev/ttyAMA* devices are appearing, the UART functions are not enabled on the correct pins. I think this is another problem with the Ubuntu kernel - 6.5.0-1008-raspi in my case."

Points to a bug in the kernel.  I raised this bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/2046841